# Python skip to another csv line

Tags: python

I have following python script:

```
import csv, time, logging, threading, requests
from colorama import init, Fore

def main():      
  with open('tasks.csv', "r", newline='') as csvfile:
                tasks = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                for line in tasks:
                    t = threading.Thread(target=loadCsv,args=(line,))
                    t.start()
                    t.join()
```

```
def loadCsv():
  try:
    something went wrong with this line in CSV file.
  except Exception as e:
    logging.info(f'''{Fore.RED} Unknown error, skipping task - {e}''')
    time.sleep(5)
    main()
```

How can I move to the next line in csv file? This script goes back, says it is Thread-2 but info stays same and doesnt change. I hope I explained my issue well! Thank you.

Comment: Since you do `t.join()` in the loop, this program is effectively single-threaded. Look into using `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` and friends instead.

Comment: Also, it's a terrible idea to recursively call `main()` within `loadCsv()`...

Comment: @AKX I need to use threading in this one. :/

Comment: Just a simple advice. Multithreading can add efficiency, but it also adds complexity. NEVER TRY TO MULTITHREAD until it works fine without threading. The last `main()` call inside a loop is terrible. Solve that part, and then ask here again if you cannot use multithreading.

Comment: @user15513823 Why do you _require_ threading? If what you mean is you need the parallelism, then multiprocessing does the trick.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Final code is a lot different, I only did this in this example to make the code smaller. It is 500 lines of code where I actually need to use this...

Comment: @user15513823 Please show more code, then. As I said, if your code wasn't weirdly recursive in the thread function, it's effectively single-threaded as it is.